# WSO2 EMM operation not applied when device locked

Tags: ios, iphone, wso2, wso2-iot

I have installed WSO2 EMM profile on iOS device. Restriction profile gets applied on devices successfully when a device is unlocked. But when the device is locked the restrictions are not getting applied.

I tried hiding camera & applied the policy on device. This works when device unlocked but not working when iOS device is locked.

I checked device operation log it shows "In Progress". Device is still online but locked.

I found that iOS device sends NotNow status which prevents this operation.
http://www.enterpriseios.com/forum/topic/Profiles_not_being_Applied_on_Locked_Device

One solution could be by doing policy apply every minute hoping device is unlocked at this moment. But that doesn't look right.

I can provide any server log required along database table status if required. Please let me know a way to overcome the problem.

Comment: What is the EMM version you are using?

Comment: I am using 2.0.1. I am using MySQL database